# My parallel code in R is slower than the sequential version?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to efficiently create and store the results of N density estimations of a random variable. To make it fast for the case of large N I attempted to parallelize with the mcapply function from the [parallelsugar package](https://github.com/nathanvan/parallelsugar). Here is my code, first I create the density estimation results with serial code using `lapply` and then parallel code using `mcapply`:

```
N <- 50
myList <- 1:N

system.time(
  densities_serial <- lapply(myList, function(x) {
    r = rnorm(100,10,1)
    r_density = density(r)
    y = r_density$y
  })
)

# remotes::install_github('nathanvan/parallelsugar')
system.time(
  densities_serial2 <- parallelsugar::mclapply(myList, function(x) {
    r = rnorm(100,10,1)
    r_density = density(r)
    r_density$y
  })
)

system.time(
  densities_serial3 <- parallel::mclapply(myList, function(x) {
    r = rnorm(100,10,1)
    r_density = density(r)
    r_density$y
  })
)
```

Unfortunately the parallel code is much, much slower than the serial code:

```
Serial   - Time taken: 0.06
Parallel - Time taken: 9.54
```

Its just as bad for larger values of N and in practise I need to use very large values of N, hence why I want to speed it up.

So why is my parallel code running so slowly? Is there anything I can do fix it? Is there some other way to run this operation in parallel that will give me a speedup?

Comment: I am using the mcapply from the parallelsugar library. The standard mcapply is not parallel in windows because it can't use forking like it does in Linux.

Comment: Takes 0.03, 106 and 0.02 on my Windows laptop. I guess this is an issue with the parallelsugar package.